# Always active Session in yii2

Tags: session, yii2

I am using yii2-basic. I want to use active sessions everywhere in yii2. How can I do it? I mean where should I put this code (layout.php? web\index.php?) or there is any config in config.php to make session auto active?

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I don't think you need this. As soon as you use `Yii::$app->session` it gets opened automatically.

Comment: @robsch yes, i know, but i want to active session as soon as they access to my website, so where should i put this code in ?

Comment: How early should it be? What do you need that for? I guess there is probably a better solution. You could create a component and load it in the [boostrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap) process.

Comment: I created my own login user function (not yii2's rbac) and i want to check users' session at every page of my site. So what should i do ? @robsch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.php config file file you could add an event handler:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
        // check Yii::$app->session
    },
    ...
];
```

There you can set [$event->isValid](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-actionevent.html#$isValid-detail) to false what would mean that the action won't get executed. This gets called on any action. See also [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#eventbeforeaction).

Or create a component that you load on bootstraping like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180098/57091).