# Call a Function Before every action in yii2 and check authentication in that function

Tags: php, yii2

Hello I wanted to check user authentication before every action execute in a common function which call before every action 
Example
I have this action in my controller. so want a function which call before this action and check authentication it authentication then that function return the fail message and below don't need to execute

```
class FrontLoginController extends ActiveController {
    public function actionActivateAccount() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180059/execute-my-code-before-any-action-of-any-controller

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 controller has function [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail) it is probably what you looking for.

From docs:

> The method will trigger the EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION event. The return
>   value of the method will determine whether the action should continue
>   to run.